# Timer() as Daemon Vs non Daemon

Tags: android, timer

```
//Creates a new Timer which may be specified to be run as a daemon thread.
Timer(boolean isDaemon)  

//Creates a new non-daemon Timer.
Timer()
```

When does a timer should be started as Daemon inside an android app ?

The documentation says nothing about it .

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: you start it, when you need it. it is really unclear what you mean

Answer (score 14):

If your application is running a user-thread (i.e. non-daemon thread) then the JVM will wait till the *return* of its `run()` method (or the thread has completed its execution) before it terminates the application. However, if your thread is set as **daemon**, then it instructs the JVM not to wait for the completion of its execution in case the JVM needs to close down the application (i.e. when no other user threads are running). Other than this, both types of  threads are treated equally in all other aspects.

In your case, you should not set your `Timer` as daemon thread, until and unless you don't want its execution to hold the termination of application.

For more information, read [this](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-difference-between-user-and-daemon-thread-in-java/196) and [this](http://www.java-forums.org/threads-synchronization/15755-should-i-run-my-timer-daemon.html).

Comment: Seeing as how Android has its own, different method for terminating processes, it is unclear to me exactly what the meaning and relevance is of whether or not an app can be closed due to the type of thread a timer has.